# prestashop and mcrypt?

Tags: php, prestashop

I have a problem with a plugin in prestashop.

I try to use a mcrypt function.

```
$passwd = "test";
$pwcrypt = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $usr_key, $passwd, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $usr_iv);
```

The returned `$pwcrypt` is wrong. It's not the same encrypted password that I have in my mysql table.
 I get the `$usr_key` and `$usr_iv` from a mysql table User.

This same script works in others website, (not included in prestashop)

I am not familiar with prestashop, does it change something in `mcrypt` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for the mcrypt blowfish algo.

Answer (score 0):

Passwords in PrestaShop are encrypted with special functon which uses salt. The function can be found at Tools::encrypt()